# Use Merge Statement By Considering All Records of a BusinessKey

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have a table that show the relationship of each account and customers of each account. The relationship between account and customer may change over time. I want to show this change with a Merge Statement in a way that if even one of the relations of an account changes, then all the past data of that account gets `IsCurrent=0` and new data gets `IsCurrent=1`. And if any of the relationships did not change then do nothing in the merge statement. By considering that I want to consider all of rows of an account for decide to change IsCurrent, StartDate, EndDate of destination table (as I show below). How can I do that?

Destination table:

| AccountId | CustomerId | RelationId | StartDate | EndDate | IsCurrent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 12 | 1 | 2022-06-02 | Null | 1 |
| 1234 | 13 | 2 | 2022-06-02 | Null | 1 |
| 1234 | 14 | 5 | 2022-06-02 | Null | 1 |

Source Table:

| AccountId | CustomerId | RelationId | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 12 | 1 | 2022-10-02 |
| 1234 | 14 | 6 | 2022-10-02 |

This is what I want to have:

| AccountId | CustomerId | RelationId | StartDate | EndDate | IsCurrent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 12 | 1 | 2022-06-02 | 2022-10-01 | 0 |
| 1234 | 13 | 2 | 2022-06-02 | 2022-10-01 | 0 |
| 1234 | 14 | 5 | 2022-06-02 | 2022-10-01 | 0 |
| 1234 | 12 | 1 | 2022-10-02 | NULL | 1 |
| 1234 | 14 | 6 | 2022-10-02 | NULL | 1 |

Comment: Be great to see what you tried.

Comment: shouldn't enddate be NULL for the two new rows in final table

Comment: Can you also explain what happens with customer = 13. It doesn't have any rows in source table, but still gets "cancelled". How does one know on which date he should be cancelled?

Comment: @siggemannen Customer=13 does not have relation with that account anymore , so it is not in source table, because we want to know that it had relation ship with that account in the past we dont delete it , instead we keep it in target table and fill enddate for it .

Comment: @siggemannen about cancel date, you assume that this merge run every day, so if for example today we do not have a customer anymore, the cancel date should be yesterday

Answer (score 0):

I don't think merge can handle this kind of upsert, but you can do it in three steps:

1. Stop accounts that no longer exist
2. Stop accounts that have new date
3. Add new/changed accounts

Some SQL ideas...

```sql
--1.
UPDATE d
SET EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
, IsCurrent = 0
FROM Destination d
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM source s
  WHERE s.accountId = d.AccountId
  AND s.CustomerID = d.CustomerID
  AND s.RelationId = d.RelationID
)
AND d.IsCurrent = 1
AND d.AccountId = 1234 -- Not sure about this one
```

I added a WHERE on accountID. Because let's say your Destination table also contained Accounts 1235, maybe they shouldn't be deactivated by missing account 1234, it's a bit unclear.

```sql
--2.
UPDATE d
SET EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, s.Date)
, IsCurrent = 0
FROM Destination d
INNER JOIN source s
  ON  s.accountId = d.AccountId
  AND s.CustomerID = d.CustomerID
  AND s.RelationId = d.RelationID
  AND s.Date > d.StartDate -- New start
WHERE d.IsCurrent = 1

--3.
INSERT INTO Destination (CustomerId, AccountID, RelationId, StartDate, Enddate,IsCurrent
)
SELECT CustomerId, AccountID, RelationId, StartDate, NULL Enddate,1 IsCurrent
FROM source s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM Destination d
  WHERE d.CustomerId = s.CustomerID
  AND d.AccountID = s.AccountID
  AND d.RelationID = s.RelationID
  AND d.StartDate = s.Date
  AND d.IsCurrent = 1
)
```

It's kinda busy though, so perhaps there's something easier, but your design is a bit complicated.

This stuff should be performed in transaction so you dont get half-baked operation